# How to use EnumProcesses in node-ffi

Tags: winapi, node-ffi

I was trying to use `EnumProcesses` with `node-ffi`. I got code below:

```
import ffi from 'ffi'

export const psapi = ffi.Library('psapi', {
  EnumProcesses: ['bool', ['ulong', 'ulong', 'uint16*']]
})

export class Win32ProcessManager {
  public async getProcessList () {

    let lpidProcess = ref.alloc('ulong*')
    const cb = 1024
    const lpcbNeeded = ref.alloc('uint16*')

    const res = psapi.EnumProcesses(lpidProcess, cb, lpcbNeeded)

    const ulongSize = (ref as any).sizeof.ulong
    const totalBytesReturned = lpcbNeeded.readInt16LE()
    const processCount = totalBytesReturned / ulongSize
    console.log(`processCount: ${processCount}`)

    // ??? How to get the value from the lpidProcess?
    return lpidProcess
  }
}
```

I tried with `ref.get` but I encountered errors:

```
    let processId = ref.get(array, 0, ref.types.ulong)
    console.log(processId)
    const pointerSize = (ref as any).sizeof.pointer
    console.log(pointerSize)
    let processId2 = ref.get(array, (ref as any).sizeof.pointer, ref.types.ulong)
    console.log(processId2)
```

Errors:

```sh
RangeError [ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]: Attempt to write outside buffer bounds
```

Anyone knows how to use `node-ffi` read the array data from dll?

Comment: You need to use a large enough array instead a pointer(which could only contain 1 element), because it is hard to predict how many processes there will be at the time you call `EnumProcesses`. BTW, you've declared the parameter type to be `ulong` but passed a `ulong*`, maybe you could use `ref-array`, and then pass count_of_array * sizeof_each_element as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Thanks for your comment! You saved my life! I spent a whole day yesterday to solve this.

Comment: NP, and you can share and post your solution as an answer and feel free to accept yourself.

Comment: Final code posted :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @DrakeWu-MSFT, I finally got my code works, here are how they looks finally:

```
import ffi from 'ffi';
import ref from 'ref';
import ArrayType from "ref-array";

export const psapi = ffi.Library('psapi', {
  EnumProcesses: ['bool', ['ulong*', 'ulong', 'uint16*']],
});

export class Win32ProcessManager {

  public getProcessIdList (): number[] {
    const processIdLength = 1024;
    const ulongSize = (ref as any).sizeof.ulong;
    const cb = processIdLength * ulongSize;
    let processIdArray = ArrayType('ulong', processIdLength);
    let lpidProcess = ref.alloc(processIdArray);
    const lpcbNeeded = ref.alloc('uint16*');

    const res = psapi.EnumProcesses(lpidProcess, cb, lpcbNeeded);

    if (res) {
      const totalBytesReturned = lpcbNeeded.readInt16LE();
      const processCount = totalBytesReturned / ulongSize;
  
      const processArray = (lpidProcess as any).deref();
      let resultProcessArray: number[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < processCount; i++) {
        resultProcessArray.push(processArray[i]);
      }
  
      return resultProcessArray;
    } else {
      console.error(`Get process list failed with result from EnumProcess: ${res}`);
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

I was struggled with getting array data from the pointer, and that was wrong, as @DrakeWu-MSFT said in the comment, because I didn't allocate enough spaces for the buffer, no data can be write into that. With `ref-array` and a pointer to the array, it works like a charm.

Comment: A little problem, `cb` should be the length of array(1024) *ulongSize, although 1024 is enough to accommodate most cases.

Comment: And you could also feel free to [accept your own answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).